# PHP Formatting Regex - BBCode

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing, bbcode

To be honest, I suck at regex so much, I would use RegexBuddy, but I'm working on my Mac and sometimes it doesn't help much (for me).

Well, for what I need to do is a function in php

```
function replaceTags($n)
{
    $n = str_replace("[[", "<b>", $n);
    $n = str_replace("]]", "</b>", $n);
}
```

Although this is a bad example in case someone didn't close the tag by using ]] or [[, anyway, could you help with regex of:

[[  ]] = **Bold format**

**  ** = **Italic format**

((  )) = **h2 heading**

Those are all I need, thanks :)

P.S - Is there any software like RegexBuddy available for Mac (Snow Leopard)?

Comment: I would look at regexlib.com for anything already made. Also, <b> tags are outdated, use <strong> instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function replaceTags($n)
{
    $n = preg_replace("/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/", "<strong>$1</strong>", $n);
    $n = preg_replace("/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/", "<em>$1</em>", $n);
    $n = preg_replace("/\(\((.*?)\)\)/", "<h2>$1</h2>", $n);
    return $n;
}
```

I should probably provide a little explanation: Each special character is preceded by a backslash so it's not treated as regex instructions ("[", "(", etc.).  The "(.*?)" captures all characters between your delimiters ("[[" and "]]", etc.).  What's captured is then output in the replacements string in place of "$1".

Comment: You might want to change the `.*` inside the match to the non-greedy `.*?` so that `[[bold]] not bold [[bold]]` won't result in `<strong>bold]] not bold [[bold</strong>`

Answer (score 1):

The same reason you can't do this with `str_replace()` applies to `preg_replace()` as well.  Tag-pair style parsing requires a lexer/parser if you want to yield 100% accuracy and cover for input errors.

Regular expressions can't handle unclosed tags, nested tags, that sort of thing.

That all being said, you can get 50% of the way there with very little effort.

```
$test = "this is [[some]] test [[content for **you** to try, ((does [[it]])) **work?";

echo convertTags( $test );

// only handles validly formatted, non-nested input
function convertTags( $content )
{
  return preg_replace(
      array(
          "/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/"
        , "/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/"
        , "/\(\((.*?)\)\)/"
      )
    , array(
          "<strong>$1</strong>"
        , "<em>$1</em>"
        , "<h2>$1</h2>"
      )
    , $content
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifiers could help too :)

http://lv.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

> **U** (PCRE_UNGREEDY) This modifier
>   inverts the "greediness" of the
>   quantifiers so that they are not
>   greedy by default, but become greedy
>   if followed by ?. It is not compatible
>   with Perl. It can also be set by a
>   (?U) modifier setting within the
>   pattern or by a question mark behind a
>   quantifier (e.g. .*?).